# Use WP cookie to authentificate user on an external app

Tags: users, cookies, authentication

Is it possible to authentificate a logged in WP user by it's wp auth cookie from an external app (simple JS webapp on a different domain)?

The setup is:

- My webapp is on domain.com/generator/
- The wordpress installation is on users.domain.com
- Same server, I have access to the WP DB

The problem: The nonce which is needed to validate the wp auth cookie is only available inside wp.
But I have to check that from outside WP.

At the moment a user always has to log in on my external app. Authentification is done using the JWT Auth Plugin.
That works perfect. I only don't like the fact, that the user has to login again although it is already logged in via WP.

Any ideas how to make it work by using the standard wp login?

What I want to know:

- Is a user logged in?
- If yes, whats the ID of that logged in user?

Comment: Can you be more specific what you mean by an external app? This could be anything from a page template in a sub-section of a site, to an iOS widget pulling in posts. To answer this we'll need a lot more information about what the app is, where it lives in relation to the site, the language it's built in, is it on the same server? The same domain? Does it have its own separate user database?

Comment: Also keep in mind that 3rd party plugin dev support is offtopic here, if your question requires JWT Auth plugin knowledge it may be impossible to answer this and stay within the sites scope

Comment: @TomJNowell I edited my post regarding the site setup. The plugin is only needed if I can't get it work with a cookie authentification.

Comment: I see, so it's a different domain, is it also a different server? Or do both have direct access to the same database? And are there other WP installs on that domain or any of the subdomains?

Comment: @TomJNowell Same server, full access to the WP database. :)